# Issues with mapping QSqlTableModel to QTreeView using QAbstractProxyModel

Tags: qt, pyside, qtreeview, qsqltablemodel, pyside6

I am trying to implement a `QAbstractProxyModel` that maps an `SqlTableModel` to a tree-like data structure. The table has a column called `parent_id`, whose value is added to the `createIndex` call as a third argument. The question is similar to [this user's post](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/69098), only that I am working in Python not in C++.

The TreeView loads correctly:

[image: see picture attached]

But when I try to expand an item, the application crashes. Debugging tells me that there seems to be an infinite loop of `index`, `rowCount` and `mapToSource` being called.

I am at the end of my wits. Do you have any ideas? See the MWE below.

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QGridLayout
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QTreeView
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget
from PySide6.QtCore import QModelIndex
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
from PySide6.QtCore import Slot
from PySide6.QtCore import QAbstractProxyModel
from PySide6.QtSql import QSqlDatabase
from PySide6.QtSql import QSqlQuery
from PySide6.QtSql import QSqlTableModel


class CustomTreeModel(QAbstractProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, database: str, parent: QWidget = None):
        QAbstractProxyModel.__init__(self, parent)
        sourceModel = QSqlTableModel(parent, database)
        sourceModel.setTable('test')
        sourceModel.select()
        self.setSourceModel(sourceModel)

    def flags(self, proxyIndex: QModelIndex) -> Qt.ItemFlags:
        return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsEditable

    def data(self, proxyIndex: QModelIndex, role: int):
        print("data")
        if proxyIndex.isValid:
            sourceIndex = self.mapToSource(proxyIndex)
            return sourceIndex.data(role)
        return None

    def index(
            self,
            row: int,
            column: int,
            parentIndex: QModelIndex
            ) -> QModelIndex:
        print("index")
        if row < 0 and column < 0:
            return QModelIndex()
        parentId = parentIndex.internalPointer()
        return self.createIndex(row, column, parentId)

    def mapFromSource(self, sourceIndex: QModelIndex) -> QModelIndex:
        print("mapFromSource")
        if self.isRootItem(sourceIndex):
            return QModelIndex()
        if sourceIndex.column() == 0:
            sourceId = sourceIndex.data()
        else:
            sourceId = sourceIndex.siblingAtColumn(0).data()
        parentId = self.getParentId(sourceId)
        childIds = self.getChildIds(parentId)
        row = childIds.index(sourceId)
        column = sourceIndex.column()
        proxyIndex = self.createIndex(row, column, parentId)
        return proxyIndex

    def mapToSource(self, proxyIndex: QModelIndex) -> QModelIndex:
        print("mapToSource")
        if self.isRootItem(proxyIndex):
            return QModelIndex()
        parentId = proxyIndex.internalPointer()
        childIds = self.getChildIds(parentId)
        rowId = childIds[proxyIndex.row()]
        rowIds = self.getAllIds()
        sourceRow = rowIds.index(rowId)
        sourceColumn = proxyIndex.column()
        sourceIndex = self.sourceModel().index(sourceRow, sourceColumn)
        return sourceIndex

    def rowCount(self, parentIndex: QModelIndex) -> int:
        print("rowCount")
        if parentIndex.column() > 0:
            return 0
        parentId = parentIndex.internalPointer()
        childIds = self.getChildIds(parentId)
        return len(childIds)

    def columnCount(self, parentIndex: QModelIndex) -> int:
        print("columnCount")
        if parentIndex.column() > 0:
            return 0
        numColumns = self.sourceModel().columnCount(parentIndex)
        return numColumns

    def parent(self, childIndex: QModelIndex) -> QModelIndex:
        print("parent")
        if childIndex.column() > 0:
            return QModelIndex()
        sourceIndex = self.mapToSource(childIndex)
        childId = sourceIndex.siblingAtColumn(0).data()
        parentId = self.getParentId(childId)
        if not parentId:
            return QModelIndex()
        parentParentId = self.getParentId(parentId)
        parentIds = self.getChildIds(parentParentId)
        parentRow = parentIds.index(parentId)
        parentIndex = self.createIndex(parentRow, 0, parentId)
        return parentIndex

    def getParentId(self, childId: str) -> str | None:
        table = self.sourceModel().tableName()
        query = QSqlQuery()
        query.prepare(f"""
            SELECT parent_id
            FROM {table}
            WHERE id=?
            """)
        query.addBindValue(childId)
        query.exec_()
        if query.first():
            parentId = query.value(0)
            return parentId if parentId else None
        return None

    def hasChildren(self, parentIndex: QModelIndex) -> bool:
        if parentIndex.column() > 0:
            return False
        parentId = parentIndex.internalPointer()
        childIds = self.getChildIds(parentId)
        return len(childIds) > 0

    def getAllIds(self) -> list[str]:
        table = self.sourceModel().tableName()
        query = QSqlQuery()
        query.prepare(f"""
            SELECT id
            FROM {table}
            """)
        query.exec_()
        ids = []
        while query.next():
            ids.append(query.value(0))
        return ids

    def getChildIds(self, parentId: str | None) -> list[str]:
        table = self.sourceModel().tableName()
        query = QSqlQuery()
        if not parentId or parentId == '':
            query.prepare(f"""
                SELECT id
                FROM {table}
                WHERE parent_id IS NULL OR parent_id=''
                """)
        else:
            query.prepare(f"""
                SELECT id
                FROM {table}
                WHERE parent_id=?""")
            query.addBindValue(parentId)
        query.exec_()

        childIds = []
        while query.next():
            childIds.append(query.value(0))
        return childIds

    def isRootItem(self, index: QModelIndex):
        return index.row() == -1 and index.column() == -1


class CustomTreeWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent: QWidget = None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.model: CustomTreeModel
        self.view = QTreeView(self)

        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.view)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    @Slot()
    def setDatabase(self):
        database = QSqlDatabase.database()
        model = CustomTreeModel(database, self)
        self.view.setModel(model)
        self.model = model


def initTestDatabase():
    query = QSqlQuery()
    query.prepare("""
        CREATE TABLE test (
            "id"    TEXT,
            "text"  TEXT,
            "parent_id" TEXT,
            PRIMARY KEY("id")
            );
            """)
    query.exec_()

    query = QSqlQuery()
    query.prepare("""
        INSERT INTO test (
            id, text, parent_id)
        VALUES
            (?, ?, ?),
            (?, ?, ?),
            (?, ?, ?),
            (?, ?, ?);
        """)
    query.addBindValue("ID101")
    query.addBindValue("Text")
    query.addBindValue(None)

    query.addBindValue("ID102")
    query.addBindValue("Text")
    query.addBindValue("ID101")

    query.addBindValue("ID103")
    query.addBindValue("Text")
    query.addBindValue("ID101")

    query.addBindValue("ID104")
    query.addBindValue("Text")
    query.addBindValue(None)
    query.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    projectDb = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
    projectDb.setDatabaseName(":memory:")
    projectDb.open()

    initTestDatabase()

    app = QApplication()
    mainWindow = QMainWindow()
    widget = CustomTreeWidget(mainWindow)
    widget.setDatabase()

    mainWindow.setCentralWidget(widget)
    mainWindow.showMaximized()

    app.exec_()
```

Comment: According to the link you provided, the `internalId()` is being used, while you're using the `internalPointer()`. They are two related but very different things, and can behave in very different ways.

Comment: The reason I am trying to use `internalPointer` over `internalId` is that `internalId` must be an integer, while `internalPointer` seems to be able to store strings (which I need).

On `internalPointer()`, I did not really find any PySide examples or documentation. [Qt doc](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtCore/QAbstractItemModel.html) only says that developers are advised to keep the objects that are passed as arguments to `createIndex` alive. I have tried that by adding unique IDs to a list stored as a class property. This did not seem to make a difference.

Comment: The problem is that a root index (hence, an invalid QModelIndex for the parent) will always return `None`, and the result is that all top level items will use that internal pointer in `createIndex()`, but this means that you'll have a shared internal pointer for all top level items and no reference for their relations with children. I never used this kind of implementation for proxies, so I really cannot help you with that, but from what I've understood so far with abstract models, you should probably provide a valid internal pointer for child items whenever they are not top level items.

Comment: Thank you for answering. If I understand you correctly then I need to pass to `createIndex` a valid `QModelIndex` object that represents the parent instead of an arbitrary datatabase Id, is that correct?

Comment: I did similar thing derived from `QAbstractItemModel` using `internalPointer`. And indeed your `index()` and `parent()` methods doesn't look good.